# Is it possible in Apache POI to look if value exists in column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm looking for a function, which would check if value exists in desired field. For example: Check if "Desired value" exists in sheet "Data" and range would be A1:A2546.

Comment: Yes, Yes it can- have you tried something?

Comment: Check `LOOKUP` function

Comment: I tried using for loop and checking if row equals that value, if not it goes to another value. But its ineffective and slow, so i was thinking if there is more efficent way.

Comment: No there is not a more effective way than looping over all rows in sheet "Data" and comparing each of the cell values of column 0 (A) with the desired value. At least not in general. If the column values are sorted, then a binary search algorithm could be used. But this depends on whether the column values are sorted.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can make use of the following:

```
public boolean checkIfValueExistsInColumn(String columnName, String valueToCheck) throws InterruptedException {

    int colNum = -1;
    // searching the file for the desired column
    for (Cell cell : dataSetHeaders) {

        if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)) {

            colNum = cell.getColumnIndex();
            break;

        }

    }

    // if desired column does not exist
    if (colNum == -1)
        throw new InterruptedException();

    for(int r = 1; r < dataSetSheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
    
                if(dataSetSheet.getRow(r).getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue().equals(valueToCheck)) {
    
                   return true;
    
                }
    
     }
    
     return false;

}
```